# Laravel query builder returns object or array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm building a very simple web app with Laravel.

I've built two separate Controllers, which each return two separate views, as follows:

ProfileController:

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController {

    public function user($name)
    {
        $user = User::where('name', '=', $name);

        if ($user->count())
        {
            $user = $user->first();
            $workout = DB::table('workouts')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();

            Return View::make('profile')
                    ->with('user', $user)
                    ->with('workout', $workout);
        }

        return App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

WorkoutController:

```
class WorkoutController extends BaseController {

    public function workout($name)
    {
        $workout = DB::table('workouts')->where('name', '=', $name)->first();

        if ($workout)
        {
            Return View::make('add-exercise')
                    ->with('workout', $workout);
        }

        return App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

What is confusing me is what I had to do in order to pass a single `workout` object to each view. As you might have noticed the query builders for `workout` are different:

```
$workout = DB::table('workouts')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
```

and

```
$workout = DB::table('workouts')->where('name', '=', $name)->first();
```

On the `profile` view, I get an object using the `->get();` method, but on the `add-exercise` view, I must use `->first();` or I will otherwise get an array with only one index, where I can then access the object, i.e. `$workout[0]->name` instead of `$workout->name`.

Why is this? Shouldn't I be able to use either `get` and/or `first` in both controllers and expect the same type of result from both since I want the same thing from the same table?

Comment: No, because a result using get() may comprise none, one or many objects; so you always get a collection back; whereas `first()` will only ever return none or one object, so it can return a straight object without needing a collection

Comment: If you `var_dump($workout)` from each, what *class* is each object? If I recall, `->get()` should return a collection of results, while `->first()` should return an object representing a single row.

Comment: that's something you need to make it manual...!! Laravel can't do that for you..!! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`get()` returns a collection of objects every time.  That collection may have 0 or more objects in it, depending on the results of the query.

`first()` calls `get()` under the hood, but instead of returning the collection of results, it returns the first entry in the collection (if there is one).

Which method you use depends on what you need. Do you need the collection of all the results (use `get()`), or do you just want the first result in the collection (use `first()`)?

Comment: And if there is no row found `first()` returns `null`

Comment: What about "where"? What does it return?

Comment: @EricMcWinNEr There are two basic query function types: modifiers and executors. Modifiers (`where()`, `select()`, `orderBy()`, etc.) modify the query before it is executed. Modifying functions return the query builder object so that you can continue to modify it, or finally execute it using an executing statement (`get()`, `first()`, `count()`, `exists()`, etc.). Executing statements return the result of the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patricus, I was confused at first, I figured it out after looking at the docs again. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

- Model::find(numeric); returns a object
- Model::whereId(numeric)->first(); returns a object
- Model::whereId(numeric)->get(); - returns a collection
- Model::whereId(numeric); - returns a builder