# Problems passing a variable to with()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble passing a variable that stores a certain value to `with()`, it returns what I want, but it returns the following message.

`[{"name":"Ryu"}] won updates in your informations.` rather then `Ryu won updates in your informations.`

```
    public function update(FighterRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();
        FighterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validations);
        $name_fighter = DB::table('fighters')->select('name')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
        return redirect('fighter')->with('success-update',"$name_fighter won updates in your informations.");  
    }
```

Comment: sounds like you want to call `value` instead of `get` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would try this version because get return multiple objects but first only object

```php
  public function update(FighterRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();
        FighterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validations);
        $name_fighter = DB::table('fighters')->select('name')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
        return redirect('fighter')->with('success-update',"$name_fighter->name won updates in your informations.");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$name_fighter` returns a collection. So rather than using `$name_fighter` directly, you need to specify what you want to get `$name_fighter->name`

Comment: I do not know who down voted this answer, but it defenetly  pointing up the person who asked a question to the right direction. Look what @Mike Baker said about this: " a result using get() may comprise none, one or many objects; so you always get a collection back; whereas first() will only ever return none or one object, so it can return a straight object without needing a collection. " Here is the link to the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176292/laravel-query-builder-returns-object-or-array

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco `$name_fighter` is a Collection, it doesn't have a property named `name` so this is incorrect, not valid ... so that is probably why

Comment: @lagbox You are absolutely right. But the fact that we can discover this issue and point up the questioner to the right direction, should we  down voted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$name_fighter = DB::table('fighters')->where('id','=',$id)->value('name');
```

Comment: Always give explanation to your answers.